# Android Automotive OS (API 31+) on Raspberry Pi stuck on startup

Tags: raspberry-pi4, android-build, android-12, android-automotive

I am trying to build an Android image for Raspberry Pi 4B with Android Automotive OS instead of the usual Android.
Following the instructions on [this repository](https://github.com/snappautomotive/firmware-device_snappautomotive_rpi/tree/sa-arpi-12L) worked from the repo sync down to the generated files I have to put onto my SD card.

The problem arises once I put the newly formatted SD card into the RPi 4b.
The rainbow screen appears, goes away and then the boot animation for AAOS appears...
And stays on it for an indefinite time.

I did try to do the same with the [original repository](https://github.com/android-rpi/device_arpi_rpi4/tree/arpi-12), modified some config to make it Automotive.
I even went to a [third repository](https://github.com/raspberry-vanilla/android_local_manifest/tree/android-12.1) and my luck failed there as well...

The modification I added was this line in the `rpi4.mk` file
`$(call inherit-product, packages/services/Car/car_product/build/car.mk)`

To add: On the latter 2 builds I did try the pure Android RPi without Automotive modification, which booted perfectly fine.
And currently we are working with an image of AAOS Version 11 (API 30) on a Raspberry Pi (albeit with some hiccups)

My question(s):

- Am I missing more configuration?
- Is it possible to build AAOS on Version 12 (especially for the Raspberry Pi)?

Comment: I tried the (outdated?) Snapp AAOS v11 image, which doesn't boot for my raspberry pi 4b with 8GB RAM. I get the rainbow screen but just a blank screen after. I then followed https://grapeup.com/blog/android-automotive-os-on-raspberry-pi-4b/# and built a SD card myself from source, which also has the same problem. Which AAOS version 11 image did you follow and what hiccups/workaround did you follow?

Comment: I actually moved to an AAOS 12 build, which worked, albeit the build is kinda bloated. I am going to [link](https://groups.google.com/g/android-rpi/c/Wf_ZoXFnHzc/m/MrNjRqdsCwAJ) the steps I did here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it and wrote my (partial) answer [on this Groups conversation](https://groups.google.com/g/android-rpi/c/Wf_ZoXFnHzc/m/MrNjRqdsCwAJ).

Back to the start, I found a way to get Debugging out of a Raspberry Pi 4 with Android while booting by following [this tutorial](https://howchoo.com/pi/raspberry-pi-gadget-mode). With that, my PC was able to detect the Raspberry Pi as an Android device in ADB (I used a USB-C to USB-C cable. Power was sufficient).

Doing `adb bugreport` and going through the logs, I discovered, that there is a service, which doesn't start, because it needs GPS, which (obviously) the Raspberry Pi 4 doesn't have in-built.

Removing the line, which initialize the service and then AAOS 12 booted as usual.

The files I added to the build might bloat the system, but for the sole purpose of having AAOS 12 running, I can't complain.

**TL;DR:** Follow [these steps](https://groups.google.com/g/android-rpi/c/Wf_ZoXFnHzc/m/MrNjRqdsCwAJ) to get AAOS 12.